# QtTest: moc file will be not generated

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build a simple unittest with QTTest. The file MyTest.cpp looks like:

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>

class MyTest : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void test() {
        QVERIFY( true );
    }
};

QTEST_MAIN( MyTest )
#include "mytest.moc"
```

Now I have create a simple pro-file to generate the executable. But while building it the compiler cannot find the created file mytest.moc, because it wasn's created. When I cann the moc-compiler manually everything worked fine.

The pro-file looks like:

```
QT +=testlib
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = unittests
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += MyTest.cpp
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I have missed? I am using VS2010, QT5.1 and Windows7.

Thanks in advance,
Kim

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html  **we also need to include the generated moc file to make Qt's introspection work.** did you add the moc file ?

Comment: @Prakash He did. BTW I didn't know qttest is so bad. Just forget about it, and use normal unittest framework (like gtest).

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code we try to include the generated file when it is there. UNfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: The tutorial that @Balu mentioned is now [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Linux. The included moc file was not regenerated and therefore was not matching the test cases. The reason is that I was mixing shadow build and in-source build, and the included moc in the shadow build was actually the stalled one from the in-source build.

The solution in this situation is to remove the moc file from the in-source build, then force rebuild (clean then build) the test class in the shadow build. It triggers the regeneration of the moc file and all tests run normaly after that.